# Como separar en diferentes puertos un proyecto de Laravel

Tags: nginx, server

Tengo un proyecto hecho con Laravel y me gustaría poder separar en puertos diferentes las rutas de la api y web.

Por ejemplo:
Tengo
API -> http://localhost:8000/api/v1/sensores

Web -> http://localhost:8000/sensores

Y lo que me gustaría conseguir es:
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/sensores

Dejando las rutas de web igual que las tengo ahora, en el puerto 8000

Estoy usando nginx como servidor

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es configurar el proxy de tu servidor. No desde el proyecto Laravel. De forma que todas las direcciones que contengan `/api/v1/*` sean atendidas por tu API y las rutas que no tengan esta expresión accedan a las vistas. ¿Que servidor utilizas? ¿Apache o nginx?

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: lo que intentas hacer es implementar Virtual Host lo que tiene que ver con configuración de servidores... lo cual no es un tópico del sitio. tu problema no es un problema de programación.